# collapsingtoolbarlayout recyclerview working separately

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Collapsing toolbar layout and the recycler view should work together while swiping but working separately.
suggest to me what to do! given below are my code and resulting gif part of my project.

the toolbar layout is not showing fully if I swipe the screen from bottom to top.
the toolbar layout is closed and only return if I swipe to toolbar layout separately.

i want to toolbar layout to be in the same manner when i swipe the screen up and down.

**Code of my layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.review.reviewActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collaps_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="true">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO"
                    android:src="@drawable/cover_image"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="title"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/review_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: I suggest not enclosing your RecyclerView in RelativeLayout and keep it as a direct child of Coordinator layout

Comment: I tried that also but the same problem.

Comment: Try removing the fitSystemWindows flag for AppBar and CollpasingToolbarLayout

Comment: tried still same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/itineraryListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground">
    
    
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            
            
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
                
                
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow_booking_details"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical" />
                
                
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_background_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_123sdp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/name_app"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/booking_details_background" />
                
                
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_background_rectangle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_123sdp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle_booking_details" />
                
                
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_background_title"
                    style="@style/font_title_bookingdetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/text_trek_everest_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
                
                
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideline9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="26dp" />
                
                
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            
            
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        
        
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        
        
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_itinerary_list"
                    style="@style/font_title_day1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
                    
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/dashboard_itinerary"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.235" />
                
                <include layout="@layout/booking_itinerary_recyclerview" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the output of this code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just inserted ```recyclerView``` inside ```NestedScrollView``` it worked